# Can't Use Gravity on two textviews in one row

Tags: android, android-layout

I use this code to make my two textviews have different gravity which are in the same row. but they don't.
code:

```
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:text="@string/text_ceo_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/text_ceo_name_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name_title"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should use RelativeLayout for this kind of design

Comment: so LinearLayout is not appropriate?

Comment: I am not sure. But I think RelativeLayout will make it easier

Comment: Try using setGravity(int) programmatically

Comment: Have you tried giving both TextView's LayoutGravity?

Comment: @YogeshSomani It does work in Linear Layout, You dont need any Relative Layout

Comment: @RajeevNB Ok thats great. I just spoke my mind.

Comment: I have tried LayoutGravity and it didn't work.

Comment: Using setGravity(int) didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working...

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <TextView android:text="me"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name"/>
        <TextView android:text="You"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name_title"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Try giving weight as per you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a view to the left of `textviews` in parent layout and use `layout_weight` for 3 views.
Like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

           <View android:layout_width="0dip" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1.0"/>

          <TextView android:text="text_ceo_name"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name"/>
            <TextView android:text="text_ceo_name_title"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name_title"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will set one text to center of layout and the other one to the right of layout.

Also [`android:gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#gravity) will set gravity to the child of the view you are using.

For setting gravity to your layout, use [`android:layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity)

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout will just not cut it in this case.

Use RelativeLayout.

Align one text view to "center in parent"
And the other text view to "Align to parent's right"

Comment: is there anyway to do this in LinearLayout? it is kind of a essential key for me.

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you could use a LinearLayout and within it use a RelativeLayout just for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:text="@string/text_ceo_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name"/>
        <TextView android:text="@string/text_ceo_name_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/txt_ceo_name_title"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Try this it may help you. One of your TextView width is fill_parent and other's TextView width is wrap_content. May be thats the problem also. Accept answer if it helps.